# Safely execute command (avoid remote execution) with Golang

Tags: shell, go, exploit

I have a small app in go that handles http requests by executing a process and providing it with some input from the query string that a user supplied with the request. I was wondering what is the best way to filter that input against remote execution. The PHP alternative for example would be something like:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Right now the input should be a valid URL if that makes it easier, but ideally a generic filter would be preferred.

Comment: If you are using [os/exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) go won't pass it through the shell so doing shell escapes isn't necessary. You should validate the input very carefully though!

Comment: Yeah using os.exec, didnt know its not passing it through the shell thats good to know. But even if it isnt something like "command && malicious" should work for example ?

Comment: Essentially php gets it wrong by offloading process execution to the shell (which isn't even guaranteed to an sh-compatible shell) and making you do the work of making it safe. Pretty much every other languages' os libraries call into the kernel directly, thus avoiding injection attacks implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally magic functions like that are very hard to get right and often they will leave your application open to attacks if you rely heavily on them.

I would recommend that you use a smart URL/request scheme to get the commands you need to run and put some level of interpretation in between the user request and your shell execution so no parameters given by the user is used directly.

You could get request that contain `?verbose=true` and translate them to `-v` on the command line eg. When dealing with user input like strings that need to be directly given to the command being run you need to do simple escaping with quotes (with a simple check to see if the input contain quotes) to ensure you don't run into a "Bobby Tables" problem.

An alternative way would be to have your program and the underlying command exchange data through pipes or files eg. which would reduce the likeliness of leaving command input an open attack vector.

Comment: I am already doing the first part that you suggest, the problem is the second argument which is a URL that the use supplies to that command Do you think that URL encoding it and enclosing in double quotes is safe enough. Again this is nothing mission critical but i rather not have giant holes like this one laying around.

Comment: That should be sufficient.

Comment: Its more of a toy thing, but I was just wondering what is the standard approach in this case. thanks for the comments